# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, boot-partition, linux-headers

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot with Windows 10, I created a partition, live USB boot using RUFUS, but when I start the Ubuntu installation it everything is okay until the "Installation type" where I can not choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10", so I go to "Something else" option where I created partition for "/" (root), "swap" and "efi", and at the end the installation failed, I don't know why. Therefor, I tried again but this time at "Updates and other software" I disabled everything except "Minimal installation". After that, the installation finished successfully, but when I plugged the USB off and reboot my laptop, Ubuntu doesn't start and it shows an error "No Boot Device Found". Also, now I can not start the Windows.

Comment: Is there room for the installation on the disk? Minimum size for / is ~7GB, but a minimum of 20-30 GB is recommended.Use Windows Disk Manager to shrink the Windows partition if you need more space.

Comment: Yes, of course. I did it

Answer (score 0):

Check if your BIOS has an option to boot only in UEFI or Legacy mode. I suspect your windows 10 installation was installed to boot in legacy mode and after the Ubuntu installation it's no longer loading because Ubuntu was installed in UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible if you have ssd windows boot manager is in ssd and the ssd is not in AHCI mode and because of this Ubuntu is unable to read efi partition and show option for dual booting .
But beware you might wreck your current windows installation while trying to switch to AHCI .
Also use Etcher to flash liveiso of ubuntu in usb